# Specify RegEx in config file C#

Tags: c#, regex

How to specify RegEx in web.config file. In my regular expression i have < and >.

Below is RegEx

```
Actual pattern="^[\p{L}0-9~&amp;!@#$%^*()_+-={}:;<,>.?\/\[\]\|\s]*$"

Modified pattern="^[\p{L}0-9~&amp;!@#$%^*()_+-={}:;&lt;,&gt;.?\/\[\]\|\s]*$"
```

Modified `<> to &lt; and &gt;`

But this pattern is not working for `>` in Modified pattern.

Comment: Give an Example will be a great idea. what is the input. What is the output and what is expected

Comment: Place the `-` at the end and see what happens.

Comment: Can't you use CDATA and avoid rewriting your pattern?

Comment: I should allow only the characters mentioned, should not allow non Unicode characters

Comment: Try `^[\\p{L}~&amp;!@#$%^(-?{}:;,./[\\]|\\s]*$`, I modified the range to `(-?` to include both `<` and `>` (this range also includes digits). Since you are using regular string literals, you need to use double escapes with `\\p{L}`, `\\s` and `\\]`.

Comment: The `+-=` fragment inside the `[...]` of your regular expression is almost certainly going to cause something unexpected. The fragment means all the characters from `+` to `=`. Compare to the `0-9` earlier in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Unicode code points: `\u003C` for `<`, and `\u003E` for `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that when defining a regex without using verbatim string literals, you need to double eacape symbols. Besides, `<` and `>` should either be serialized as `&gt;` or `&lt;` or put into CDATA section, or you can use smart ways of matching them.

I suggest using a `(-?` range that will include the angle brackets. It will also match digits, `*` and some other characters from your regex shortening it a bit:

```
^[\\p{L}~&amp;!@#$%^(-?_{}:;,./[\\]|\\s]*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%7E%26!%40%23%24%25%5E(-%3F_%7B%7D%3A%3B%2C.%2F%5B%5C%5D%7C%5Cs-%5D*%24&i=123%3D%203%5Easd%7E%26!%40%23%24%25%5E(-%3F%7B%7D%3A%3B%2C.%2F%5B%5D%7C%5D*()_%2B)